# Web scraping (Protein Data Bank) highly nested tags using beautifulsoup and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a CSV file of all protein names, their PDB (Protein Data Bank) Ids, and the Experiment method based on an advanced search query on RSPB. There are 444 search results and I wanted to create a neat CSV file.  [Here is the link](https://www.rcsb.org/search?request=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22terminal%22%2C%22service%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22negation%22%3Afalse%2C%22value%22%3A%22plasmodium%20falciparum%22%7D%2C%22node_id%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22terminal%22%2C%22service%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22operator%22%3A%22exact_match%22%2C%22negation%22%3Afalse%2C%22value%22%3A%22Homo%20sapiens%22%2C%22attribute%22%3A%22rcsb_entity_source_organism.ncbi_scientific_name%22%7D%2C%22node_id%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22label%22%3A%22text%22%7D%5D%2C%22label%22%3A%22query-builder%22%7D%2C%22return_type%22%3A%22entry%22%2C%22request_options%22%3A%7B%22scoring_strategy%22%3A%22combined%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%5B%7B%22sort_by%22%3A%22rcsb_entry_info.resolution_combined%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22asc%22%7D%5D%2C%22pager%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A0%2C%22rows%22%3A25%7D%7D%2C%22request_info%22%3A%7B%22src%22%3A%22ui%22%2C%22query_id%22%3A%226878ab86935e083352a6914232c8b2e5%22%7D%7D) of the search.

I have written the following script to extract information about first search result but the output says "None".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source = requests.get(url)  # url is same as mentioned above 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
item1 = soup.find('div', class_='row results-item')
```

The HTML code of the page seems to be highly nested and confusing.

**TL;DR**
I'm trying to get the following in a csv but the HTML is highly nested :(

1) PDB ID (4 digit alphanumeric code)
2) Protein complex name (Ex : The Fk1 domain of FKBP51....)
3) Method (X-ray diffraction, NMR etc)

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Getting a "page not found" error from your link

Comment: @JuanC I've edited the link, could you please have a look at it now? The tag I'm looking for is highly nested. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually u cant scrape this kind of website with BeautifulSoup.. This website uses internal cdn for rendering data on webpage..However I have come up with a soulution to fetch the data as JSON format..

```
import requests
headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P 
            Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
            Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Mobile Safari/537.36"
          }
payload = {
           "query":{"type":"group","logical_operator":"and","nodes": 
           [{"type":"group","logical_operator":"and","nodes": 
           [{"type":"group","logical_operator":"and","nodes": 
           [{"type":"terminal","service":"text","parameters": 
           {"negation":False,"value":"plasmodium falciparum"},"node_id":0}, 
           {"type":"group","logical_operator":"and","nodes": 
           [{"type":"terminal","service":"text","parameters": {"operator":"exact_match","negation":False,"value":"Homosapiens","attribute":"rcsb_entity_source_organism.ncbi_scientific_name"},"node_id":1}]}]}],"label":"text"}],"label":"query-builder"},"return_type":"entry","request_options":{"scoring_strategy":"combined","sort":[{"sort_by":"score","direction":"desc"}],"pager":{"start":0,"rows":100}},"request_info":{"src":"ui","query_id":"6878ab86935e083352a6914232c8b2e5"}}

response = requests.post('https://www.rcsb.org/search/data', headers=headers, 
json=data)
print(response.json())
```

You can also play with the payload values to manipulate responses..Hope this will help You!!

Comment: Hello @pritam, the code seems to return an error. I did not understand what you meant by 
'''json = data'''  
The object data hasn't been defined yet. Kindly do let me know if I am mistaken. Thanks !

Comment: oops.. should be *json=payload*, my bad!